# Dynamic Control in customiser

Tags: customization, theme-customizer

I need to build a select on my theme customise screen from this foreach:

```
foreach($wp_registered_sidebars as $sidebar_id => $sidebar)
{
    if($sidebar_id == $val)

    $sidebar_id.$sidebar['name']
}
```

Here is the code for the setting and control for custom sidebar selection.

The dynamic list would need to go in the 'choices' => array();

Is this even possible?

```
    // Add Layout setting
$wp_customize->add_setting(
    // ID
    'sidebar_left_selection',
    // Arguments array
    array(
        'default' => 'none',
        'type' => 'option',
    )
);

// Add Layout control
$wp_customize->add_control(
    // ID
    'sidebar_left_selection',
    // Arguments array
    array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'label' => __( 'Sidebar Left Selection', 'webcodexcustomizer' ),
        'section' => 'layout_section',
        'choices' => array(
            'none' => __( 'None', 'webcodexcustomizer' ),
            'sidebar_test' => __( 'Test Sidebar', 'webcodexcustomizer' ),
        ),
        'priority' => 36
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, you have to create a new class extending WP_Customize_Control:

```
    // Add Layout setting
$wp_customize->add_setting(
    // ID
    'sidebar_left_selection',
    // Arguments array
    array(
        'default' => 'none',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'webcodexcustomizer_sanitize_sidebar_selection'
    )
);

 class customize_sidebar_selection extends WP_Customize_Control {
 public function render_content() 
 {
global $wp_registered_sidebars;


// The actual fields for data entry
$output = "<span>" . esc_html( $this->label ) . "</span>";
$output .= "<select name='custom_sidebar_left'>";

// Add a default option
$output .= "<option";
if($val == "default")
    $output .= " selected='selected'";
$output .= " value='default'>".__('default', $themename)."</option>";

// Fill the select element with all registered sidebars
foreach($wp_registered_sidebars as $sidebar_id => $sidebar)
{
    $output .= "<option";
    if($sidebar_id == $val)
        $output .= " selected='selected'";
    $output .= " value='".$sidebar_id."'>".$sidebar['name']."</option>";
}

$output .= "</select>";


echo $output;
}
}

// Add Layout control
$wp_customize->add_control( 
    new customize_sidebar_selection( 
        $wp_customize, 'sidebar_left_selection', array(
            'label' => 'Sidebar Left Selection',
            'section' => 'layout_section',
            'priority' => 36,
        ) 
    ) 
);
```